# Flex DropDown event for selection changed

Tags: apache-flex

Trying to add handling for when the selected item changes in a drop-down. However, the Change/Changing events are fired before the drop down panel closes. This is too soon. I need to do some handling *after* the drop down is closed with the new selected value. Any suggestions?

Comment: only solution I found so far is to listen for Change and then use callLater to do the actual processing.. but needless to say this is awful.

Comment: Just a guess: Would saving the Change event in a private var in the event handler, then acting in the Close event handler if the same private var is set to anything, then resetting that var back to null work for you? Not sure about the timing of the Close event.

Comment: What component are you using?  The MX comboBox?  Or the Spark DropDownList?  or the Spark ComboBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always rely on the "close" event. Watch for close to happen and pick the selected item for the DDL. In case you want to be sure that CHANGE happened, add both the event listeners i.e. for CHANGE and CLOSE, if CHANGE is called before CLOSE, then you are sure that CHANGE has happened. Hope it helped.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  I needed the selection event to to force closing the dropdown list...